# How to build a function that is tangent to a sinoidal function

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots

I am trying to design a function f defined, for every $x>0$, by $ax$ where $a$ is a constant value that I am searching for. Now, the problem is, for a fixed $c>0$, find $a$ such that the equation

$$ax - 2*\sin^2(x/c)=0$$

has only two roots. In other words, find the straight line that is tangent to $2*\sin^2(x/c)$ and passes through 0.

I have been trying to define $a=4\sin(x/c)\cos(x/c)/c$, i.e., the derivative of $2*\sin^2(x/c)$, and reformulate the above problem as finding $c$ such that

$$x4\sin(x/c)\cos(x/c)/c - 2*\sin^2(x/c)=0$$

has two roots. But this does not seem to be simpler. Does someone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to find a point $P\equiv (x,f(x))$ such that:
$$
f'(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=a
$$
with $f(x)= 2\sin^2\left(\dfrac{x}{c}\right)$.
since $f'(x)= \dfrac{2}{c}\sin\left(\dfrac{2x}{c}\right)$
you have the equation:
$$
x\dfrac{2}{c}\sin\left(\dfrac{2x}{c}\right)=2\sin^2\left(\dfrac{x}{c}\right)
$$
that, I fear, we can not solve with finite formula (and has, obviously, infinite roots).